# Get original copies of objects in LINQ-to-SQL changeset

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

When using LINQ-to-SQL it is possible to get a set of arrays of objects that will be updated, inserted, or deleted by calling `DataContext.GetChangeSet()`. If there are conflicts, the `DataContext.ChangeConflicts` property will give you references to the original and changed objects. Is there a way to access the original and changed objects if there is no conflict?

This needs to work for entities that do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanging`/`INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var db = new DataContext();
db.GetChangeSet().Updates.ForEach(o => {
    var currentObject = o;
    var originalObject = db.GetTable(o.GetType()).GetOriginalEntityState(o);
    var changedProperties = db.GetTable(o.GetType()).GetModifiedMembers(o);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a way to do this through the public API. However, if you're willing to muck around with reflection a bit (and preferably, [some compiled expressions to invoke any methods, constructors, and get accessors](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/vagif/archive/2010/04/02/don-t-use-activator-createinstance-or-constructorinfo-invoke-use-compiled-lambda-expressions.aspx)), it is possible to get at the data.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Get a reference to the private `services` field of your `DataContext` instance.
2. Create an instance of `System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor`. This is an internal class that is actually used when you call `DataContext.GetChangeset()`. Pass in the reference to `services` from step 1, as well as a reference to the `DataContext` instance.
3. Call the private and parameterless `GetOrderedList` method against your `ChangeProcessor` instance. This will give you a `List<TrackedObject>`. Unfortunately, since `TrackedObject` is also an internal class, you'll need to use reflection to access its properties as well.
4. The objects we're looking for are in the `Current` and `Original` properties of the `TrackedObject` instances. It also has some other helpful properties, such as `IsNew`, `IsModified`, and `IsDeleted`, which are all self-explanatory, as well as `IsInteresting`, which I'm assuming represents any of the 3 former properties being true.

Of course, since these are all internal APIs, they are subject to change when the framework gets updated, so keep that in mind when using this logic.